# Как выровнять колонки bootstrap в одну линию?

Tags: bootstrap

Не могу понять почему блоки не ложатся в одну плоскость последний блок съезжает вниз, хотя все должно работать, на месте 3-го блока стоят пробелы???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap-3</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">Блок 1</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">Блок 2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">Блок 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: перенес ваш код в пример кода - и в примере всё корректно, блоки отображаются в одну строку. Попробуйте уменьшить масштаб страницы, авось у вас просто свободное место на экране по ширине недостаточно

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin вы отформатировали код, проблема в котором была вызвана лишними пробелами (Em Space) перед div, тем самым сделав проблему невоспроизводимой. А Andrii, который эту проблему заметил, заминусовали.

Comment: @PashaPash о таком и не подумал. Просто люблю когда код правильно отформатирован, поэтому посчитал что для удобства это первое что нужно сделать. Возможно поэтому и не сталкиваюсь с подобными ошибками

Comment: @PashaPash как раз там он был и не правильно отформатирован, как показал PHPStorm

Comment: @Andrii Да, просто нельзя править форматирование вопросов, на которые уже дан ответ "проблема в форматировании" :) Кстати, проблема не столько в форматировании, сколько в хитрых пробелах, из которых отступы состояли. Там были em space (" "), а не просто пробелы (" "). Не знаю, как их можно было случайно ввести с клавиатуры - скорее всего были скопипащены откуда-то.

Comment: Проплюсовал всех как виновный в принятии этой правки, сорри)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя между блоками есть пробелы лишние. Проверь в IDE.

Вот тебе скрин с нотпада:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло! Слона и не приметил ;))

Comment: @Василий Пожалуйста ))) Только 2 человека посчитало что я кривой ответ дал ))) Совет на будущее юзай норм IDE. И не будет таких проблем с пробелами. Он сам за тебя все сделает

Comment: Самое забавное что у меня была проблема связана не с этим (я забыл row ),но черт подери - сработало)))